# Can we create instance method with out self

Tags: python

I am trying to create class that having one instance method, is it possible to create instance method without self.

```
class A():
    def display():
        print("Hi")

a = A()
a.display()
```

I am getting like this: Type Error: display() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: can you elaborate on your usecase, why do you want an instance method (not static method!) without self?

Answer (score 2):

For an **instance method**, you need to add a parameter that represents the instance itself. It MUST be present and it MUST be the first parameter of the method - that's mandatory, you cannot change this. It can be called whatever you want, although `self` is the standard used by the community, which you should also follow.

```
class A():

    def display(self):
        print('Hi')
```

Now, as you probably noticed, we're not doing anything in particular with the instance in the `display` method. To avoid this redundancy, we need to use a different type of method.

A method which does not take an instance as an argument is called a **static method** and is represented by the `@staticmethod` decorator directy above the function definition:

```
class A():

    @staticmethod
    def display():
        print('Hi')
```

Both snippets will run without errors and, producing the same output when you execute the following code:

```
a = A()
a.display()
```

But the second version is preferred - because explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: plus the second can be called with `A.display` instead of `A().display`. Plus you cannot call an instance method from a staticmethod but you can call a staticmethod from a staticmethod!

Answer (score 0):

Using `@staticmethod` will work... but I won't recommend it for beginner uses

Usually function define an object behavior so you'll need the object itself using self !

Comment: Yaaa I know about staic method will work for this but it will not work on ay instance or any c lass variables and methods.My question is can we create instance method with out self or not

Comment: No as the method you try to call referes to an object as mentionned by @jfaccioni

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, an instance method must have at least one parameter, as the object itself is passed (implicitly) as the first argument. But *why*?

This `def` statement, like any other, defines a *function*, not a method. So where does the method come from? Let's go step by step.

```
class A:
    def display(self):
        print("Hi")
```

If we look directly in the dictionary that stores a class's attributes, we see that `display` is bound to an instance of `function`.

```
>>> type(A.__dict__['display'])
<class 'function'>
```

We get the same result if we try to access the attribute using the normal dot syntax:

```
>>> type(A.display)
<class 'function'>
```

But something ... different ... happens if we try to access that function via an *instance* of the class:

```
>>> type(A().display)
<class 'method'>
```

Where did the method come from? Anytime you access an attribute, the machinery that handles such access looks to see if the result has a `__get__` method. The `function` type provides such a method, so instead of getting the function itself back, you get the result of calling that function's `__get__` method. That is, `A().display` is *really* the same as `A.display.__get__(A(), A)`. And what `__get__` returns is an object that does two things:

1. Saves a reference to the instance `A()`
2. Saves a reference to the function `A.display`.

When you try to *call* this object, what it does is takes any arguments passed to it, and passes the saved reference to `A()` along with those arguments to the function `A.display`. That is,

```
a = A()
a.display() == A.display.__get__(a, A)(a)
```

An *that's* why `display` gets defined with one more argument than is seemingly necessary.

---

Others have also mentioned static methods. What does `@staticmethod` do? `staticmethod` is another type, whose instances wrap a function. The `staticmethod` definition of `__get__`, though, doesn't do anything other than return the underlying function, not any kind of new `method` object. So given

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def display():
        print("Hi")
```

we can see that `display` is an instance of `static method`, not a function:

```
>>> >>> type(A.__dict__['display'])
<class 'staticmethod'>
```

and that the `__get__` method returns the function itself, whether the attribute is accessed via the class

```
>>> type(A.display)
<class 'function'>
```

or an instance

```
>>> type(A().display)
<class 'function'>
```